# error while importing py2exe with lxml etree

Tags: python, lxml

How do I make py2exe import my etree.pyd in the lxml folder?

When I do

```
includes = ['lxml.etree']
```

I get the error: `importerror no module named lxml.etree`. If I go into the python console and type

```
from lxml import etree
import lxml
lxml.etree
```

Both work just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, to get the stupid mistake (that I always make) out of the way: Are you sure you're using the same Python interpreter and environment in your console and in your `py2exe` run?

Comment: Second, why are you explicitly adding this `includes`? Does the module-finder not find it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need to make this explicit; the module-finder should find the dependency and add it automatically—and if it doesn't, and you don't know of a good reason for that, you should debug it (with `py2exe.mf` as described in the docs) first.

But if you do need this, you're going to need the whole `lxml` package, not just `lxml.etree`. So, just replace:

```
includes = ['lxml.etree']
```

… with:

```
packages = ['lxml']
```

Or, if you want to include just the top level of the package and the `etree` subpackage—I'm not sure whether that will actually work (either at setup time or at runtime), but it might:

```
includes = ['lxml', 'lxml.etree']
```